# How to Pass kwarg to Filter, Getting Error Object is not Callable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework want to pass a `kwarg` to my `ClubFilter` class from within my view.

```
class ClubView(ListCreateView):

    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ClubFilter

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

So I tried added `self.filter_class = ClubFilter(**kwargs)` to the list methoud but I get the error:

**'ClubFilter' object is not callable**

How can I pass in kwarg to my filter from the view?

Comment: You would have to get the data from a query param or post data. E.g. Override get_queryset() and inspect the request object for where you expect that data.

Comment: @theWanderer4865 It's not about where I'm getting the data from, assume I have that, it's how I can pass in the ``kwargs`` to the filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter_class` must be an class, it can't be class instance. So you must pass that variable when filter object is created.

Creating of filter object is done in filter backend, so you should subclass your filter backend and provide in it some method that can take your kwargs.

Im assuming that you're using `DjangoFilterBackend`. You can then subclass it like this:

```
class MyFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        filter_class = self.get_filter_class(view, queryset)o

        if filter_class:

            if hasattr(view, 'get_filter_kwargs'):
                filter_kwargs = view.get_filter_kwargs(queryset=queryset)
            else:
                filter_kwargs = {'queryset': queryset}

            return filter_class(request.query_params, **filter_kwargs).qs

        return None
```

That will allow you to create method `get_filter_kwargs` inside your view, that should return all kwargs that shuld be passed into your filter class. Remember to pass also queryset that is provided in kwarg for that method.

Comment: I see, so DjangoFilterBackend actually reads the methods in from the view so we can just tell it to read in the new method, nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom filter backend

## filters.py

```
class MyFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        filter_class = self.get_filter_class(view, queryset)

        if filter_class:
            return filter_class(request.query_params, queryset=queryset, **kwargs).qs

    return queryset
```

and use it instead DjangoFilterBackend